# find and return the entry with the lowest mark

Tags: java

What I'm supposed to do is have a method which returns type of `Map.Entry<String, Integer>`

A method which goes through a argument `Map<String, Integer>`
and returns  type `Map.Entry<String, Integer>`
which has the lowest Integer.

```
    public static Entry<String, Integer> findLowest(Map<String, Integer> map)
    {
      int min = 10000;
      String nm ="";
      Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> ss = map.entrySet();
      System.out.println("map entryset"+map.entrySet());
      Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> it = ss.iterator();
      Map.Entry<String, Integer> e = null;
      Map.Entry<String, Integer> ee = e;
      while(it.hasNext())
      {
          e = it.next();
          System.out.println("e.getvalue: "+ e.getValue());
          System.out.println("min: "+ min);
          if(e.getValue() < min)
          {
            System.out.println("lower than");
            min = e.getValue();
            nm = e.getKey();

          }
      }
      System.out.println(ee);
      return e;
  }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: as a side node, initialize `min` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to not create bugs once every value is greater than 10000.

Comment: well the question is how to make it work so that the method returns the lowest entry, Map.entry<String, Integer>

Comment: how am i supposed to save the entry when i find which one is the lowest..and return this entry

Comment: @NickCharatsidis instead of storing the `key` and `value` for the `Entry`, store the `Entry` in a variable... or return `map.get(nm)`...

Comment: @KevinEsche He even has a variable, `ee`, reserved for that.

Comment: Yes did it finally wow i just instead of storing the min and nm variables i did ee = e and return ee
and btw AMAZING community thx for the instant helps!!!!! im really impressed! !! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of ways to do this, my preference is this:

```
   public static Map.Entry<String, Integer> findLowest(Map<String, Integer> map) {
    Map.Entry<String, Integer> result = null;
    if (map != null && !map.isEmpty()) {
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
        result = it.next();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, Integer> current = it.next();
            if (current.getValue() < result.getValue()) {
                result = current;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are allowed to use Java 8 you can use `min` method from stream of entries. Just provide Comparator which will compare values of entry.

```
 public static Map.Entry<String, Integer> findLowest(Map<String, Integer> map){
    return map.entrySet()
              .stream()
              .min(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
              .orElse(null);
 }
```

Comment: The greatness of Java-8 in a line!.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the "correct" direct answers you already got from other folks, I have a different suggestion for you: if finding the "minimum" value is an operation that happens more often in your environment, consider using data structures that help you solving that "frequent" problem of yours.

A brute force thingy could be: use a "reverse" `Map<Integer, String>` that keeps track of this relationship. Then you could look into using a `SortedMap` that makes it much easier/quicker for you to find the "smallest" key.

But of course, it depends on your use case, if having two maps (which you need to keep in sync of course) is worth the performance gained by doing so.

Answer (score 0):

```
            HashMap<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            hm.put("second", 2);
            hm.put("third", 3);
            hm.put("fourth", 4);
            hm.put("first", 1);
            Set<Entry<String, Integer>> set = hm.entrySet();
            List<Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>(
                    set);
            Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
                public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1,
                        Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
                    return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
                }
            });

            return list.get(0);  //will return lowest value from that entry set

        }
```